# Options to run a commnd remotely over ssh

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

I have numerous test servers.  These test servers get re-imaged frequently, and they have the same user account and password after being re-imaged.  I want to write a python script that runs a command remotely over ssh on one of these servers, without prompting user for a password, and gathers the output of the command.  In some circumstance I want to run one command, get output, analyze the output.  In other situation, I want to run several commands at a time (possibly run a script file).  I read many postings about running commands remotely, using third party packages (e.g. [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/)).  Is there a recommended way to achieve this task without using additional packages ? The server from which my script will be run might not have the package installed.

Or should I used [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) ?

Ideally I would like to use `subprocess` and capture the output (providing password as an argument).  Of course, my script has to handle the case when the client is logging for first time, and prompted to add ssh key to `.ssh/knownhosts` file.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: I think using the command line tool dsh is what you want

Comment: This is a bit opinion based. I tryied `paramiko`, which is a nice ssh support for Python. However, it's really slow (I was in the same case than you, running like 100 commands on 40 different accounts nor servers). Paramiko is really easy to install in standalone (it just require `python-dev` package). Didn't try pexpect.

Comment: When I made my program, I didn't find any good way to run ssh commands without any additional library (except by doing a system call to the `ssh` command using `subprocess`, **which is not a solution**).

Comment: You can use fabric, paramiko (lower level), or subprocess. Do you need to enter a password onto your machines or do you have your ssh key on them?

Comment: What is wrong with using additional packages? Is this a constraint you have or just wondering? I'd go for `pexpect` I found it really convenient for this kind of situation with multiple scenarios but that's really a personal preference I guess.

Comment: I will have to enter a password.  And these are all test machines, with the same password.

Comment: All I want to do is run a command remotely (without being prompted for a password), preferably pass the password when I make the call to ssh.  Get the output of command into a buffer which I will process.  There much be simple package (function call wrapper to subprocess) that does this.  I thought about pexpect and I don't feel it is the right tool for this job.  I feel pexpect (just like expect), is to facilitate working with an external interactive program, and drive that external program based on some "string" output by the external program.  I will look into fabric and paramiko.

Comment: Instead of setting the same password on all machines, make sure they all have the same authorized_keys file (see comment to my answer). A lot easier and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

If host key security is not an issue (you are on a trusted network etc), you can bypass the host checking. And if you use key-based authentication there is no need for a password prompt:

```
ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oPasswordAuthentication=no \
  -n doctor@tardis some_cmd
```

This way you can just use `subprocess` as if you executed `some_cmd` locally.

Comment: I think the options you suggested helps with avoiding answering the question "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?".  However, a password is still required.  With the options suggested, I get the following error msg : Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: You need to have your public key (`~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub`) in the target machine's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: I understand you proposed solution.  But these are tests systems that I have a no control over, nor authority to tell the admin of the servers to install these keys when a fresh install is done.  Hence my post to solicit ideas about my approach.  Thank you though.